# trouble in using room with rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I'm new to RxJava and I wonder what is the best way to integrating RxJava with android room.
I've seen two ways to do that:

1.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{

@Insert
void insert(User user);

}


class Repository {

public Completable <Boolean> insertUser(final User user) {
    return Completable.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            mAppDatabase.userDao().insert(user);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

}
```

2.

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{

@Insert
Completable insert(User user);

}
```

So is there any difference between above codes?Which one is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room supports RxJava2. You will probably need to add dependency `android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$version`.

Moreover, starting with Room 2.1.0-alpha01, DAO methods annotated with @Insert, @Delete or @Update support Rx return types Completable.

I recommend you to take a look to the following article where you can find detailed instruction - [Room  RxJava](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757).

As the result your DAO will look like the following and there will be no need to transform to rx type inside repository:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{
    @Insert
    Completable insert(User user);

    }
}
```